# Improve Search Box?

Tags: feature-request, search

I have a feature suggestion I would like to put out there.

I think it would be very helpful to add some sort of dropdown menu next to the search box at the top.  It could list something like "Stack Overflow" , "Meta", "Server Fault", "Super User", "My Questions"

Then you could pick 1 and type in your search query and it will pass it on to the appropriate site, it would integrate the "Family" of sites a lot better.  Obviously if you were on stackoverflow and you picked to search serverfault, it would not load the resuls on SO but would redirect you to serverfault or possibly open a new window.

This could then have a simple option to search your own questions because typing in user:745 [php] or user:me [php] it could populate the search box with that for you already (often I have to come to Meta and search for how to find my questions because I forget the syntax sometimes.

Just my thoughts

Here is a screenshot of how myspace does it...
[alt text http://img2.pict.com/69/0d/97/2565293/0/screenshot2b202.png](http://img2.pict.com/69/0d/97/2565293/0/screenshot2b202.png)
[alt text http://img2.pict.com/98/f1/4a/2565295/0/screenshot2b203.png](http://img2.pict.com/98/f1/4a/2565295/0/screenshot2b203.png)

Answer (score 1):

I don't like that combobox idea much, it doesn't help users a lot, it just saves you a tab or a link click.

What would be helpful IMO is that, by default, all searches are done on the three main sites (SF, SO and SU), using as main site the current one.

Then if there is a hit on one of the other sites with a high relevance it is shown in the results page, clearly marked by its origin site.

Google does a similar thing on some cases (on queries rather than on places, but the idea is similar,) it offers you the results for the query you've specified and, if it knows a very common query similar to yours it offers the results for that query following the results for your query.

Comment: I like this idea too however this method turns 1 query into 3 for every single search ( wayyyyyy more resources for the servers ) Thats the only reason I don't think this will happen but who knows?

Comment: That's not necessarily true. You may turn a single query over a single database in a single query over 3 databases

Answer (score 0):

I think the search box should be more intelligent. That is, if I want to search for a particular user in the search box, it ought to return users. That is a 'nice to have' feature.